# Warning Unexpected text in layout file and app crashes on click

Tags: android, android-layout

Getting Warning : unexpected text found in layout file : ""

Also on clicking the button, app is crashing.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:id="@+id/container">

<Button android:id="@+id/bntStartService"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:text="@string/broadcast_intent"
    android:onClick="broadcast_intent">
    </Button>
</LinearLayout>
```

Please help.

Comment: have you closed the LinearLayout  tag?

Comment: post the Activity code.

Comment: Yes in the last line.

Comment: @Raghunandan - Please clarify.

Comment: @him its not a crash. Is this the full layout code that you have

Comment: @Raghunandan : You pointed the right thing. With exception I came to know that I have given wrong declaration of one method. Thanks

Comment: @Him warning and crash are different. a crash means you need to post the stacktrace

Comment: I don't think that there is anything wrong in this xml file... the application is crashing when you click the button ? if yes, can you share your click listener method...?

Answer (score 0):

```
// try this way hope this will help you...
1. activity_main.xml
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/container">

    <Button android:id="@+id/bntStartService"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/broadcast_intent"
        android:onClick="broadcast_intent">
    </Button>
</LinearLayout>

2.MainActivity .java
public class MainActivity extends Activity{

    private Button bntStartService;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        bntStartService = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bntStartService);
        bntStartService.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                broadcast_intent(view);
            }
        });

    }

    private void broadcast_intent(View view){
        Toast.makeText(this,"Button Clicked",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```